# Compact framework socket timeout

Tags: multithreading, sockets, compact-framework, timeout, connection

I have problem detecting the loss of socket connection in CF app for PDA device.
I have static class that has static methods for communication (Connect(), Write(), Disconnect()). Static because all forms can call Write method.

In Connect method i call socket.Connect(ipEndpoint); 
But when device hasn't got wifi connection program halts at this line for about 20 s which is too long. Also if user starts Write() method (saving some data) and wifi connection is lost, user cannot interact with form and thinks that application frizzed. Since there is no timeout option for CF socket connection, what is the best way to control socket behavior? 
My idea is to show some kind of  "Communication form" when socket doesn't response for 5 seconds which will try to reestablish connection. This form will have graphical indicator (rotating clock or something like that) to show user that program is trying to connect and exit button if user decides to exit app. If socket.connect succeeds, i will show last used form to user.
I assume that this has to be done with Threads, but since i don't have experience with it. i need help how to manage this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Socket.BeginConnect() to launch the connect in the background.  You can then specify the callback method that will get invoked when the socket has connected (or timed-out).  Additionally, to implement your progress bar counting down as it tries to connect you can do:

```
IAsyncResult ar = moSocket.BeginConnect(...)
```

And then you can have your connection form use a timer to count down, checking the status of the connection by calling:

```
ar.IsComplete
```

Polling is not very efficient, but in this case it works well with your described pop-up connection form.